# How to popup a panel when clicking a URL in rails?

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, popup

I'm new to rails and I need to know how to pop-up a panel by clicking a URL ?? Please can some one give me solution for this problem.

Comment: Do you have any examples of what you would like to do?

Comment: I need to pop-up panel when I click particular URL. That URL contains path to the data which shows on the pop-up panel.         For example I need to show my event in pop-up panel            e.g-:  %(<a href="/events/#{event.id}" title="#{h(event.name)}">#{h(event.name)}</a>)

Comment: The answers below will do this, Matt's will open a lightbox inside the current window over the top of the other content and Mathew's will open a new small browser window.

Next time you ask a question on stackoverflow try to add as much info to the initial question as possible.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You could look at modal dialogs by www.jqueryui.com.  Add jquery ui to your application.

Put a hidden div (display:none) in your layout page.

```
<div class="modal" style="display:none;">
</div>
```

Your link should be an ajax link:

```
<%= link_to 'Link', events_path(@event), :remote => true %>
```

Your controller should accept ajax response:

```
def show
  @event = Event.find(params[:id])
  respond_to do |format|
    format.js
  end
end
```

This is where the magic happens.  After pressing the link via ajax, your show.js file will insert content into your empty hidden div and display the popup.  Your views should have a javascript file: /view/events/show.js.erb

```
$('.modal').html("<%= escape_javascript(render(@event)) %>"); //inserts content into your empty div, be aware that the parameter needed to be quoted.
$('.modal').dialog(); //jquery ui will open it as a modal popup
```

In the example above it will render an event partial.  So you should make it by creating an _event.html.erb file in /views/events/

Comment: When I try to follow your guidelines it doesn't popup a panel but it shows the event details in text like below

Comment: $('.modal').html("<p>\n  <b>Name:<\/b>\n  Ruby\n<\/p>\n\n<p>\n  <b>Start at:<\/b>\n  2011-08-30 00:00:00 UTC\n<\/p>\n\n<p>\n  <b>End at:<\/b>\n  2011-09-01 00:00:00 UTC\n<\/p>\n<p>\n  <b>Trainer:<\/b>\n  kapil\n<\/p>\n\n<p>\n  <b>Venue:<\/b>\n  IFS Colombo Sri Lanka\n<\/p>\n\n\n\n\n");

Comment: Ahh, you are almost there.  I forgot to include quotes in the javascript: `$('.modal').html("<%= escape_javascript(render(@event)) %>");`

Comment: You can also use jquery replaceWith(): `$('.modal').replaceWith("<div class='modal'><%= escape_javascript(render(@event)) %></div>");`

Comment: @ Robin : I try to do as you say by adding quotes in the javascript. But still it give that output. So wt could be the problem. Other way also giving same result :(

Comment: make sure you have format.js in your show action. and can you tell me what version of rails you are using. try updating to latest version.

Comment: Ok it might be because you are using the rails default prototype instead of jquery.  Its my personal preference to use jquery.  If that is the case, change ```$('.modal').html()``` to ```$('.modal').replace()``` etc.  Install jquery: http://railscasts.com/episodes/136-jquery or use prototype: http://api.prototypejs.org/dom/Element/prototype/replace/

Answer (score 5):

Take a look at [Shadowbox](http://www.shadowbox-js.com/), [Colorbox](http://colorpowered.com/colorbox/) or [Lightbox](http://www.huddletogether.com/projects/lightbox2/).

Code example using **Shadowbox**:

in your head tag:

```
<%= stylesheet_link_tag "shadowbox" %>
```

in the application layout (before closing your body tag):

```
<%= javascript_include_tag "shadowbox.js" %>
<script type="text/javascript">
  Shadowbox.init({
    handleOversize: "drag",
    overlayColor: '#fff'
  });
</script>
```

And in your views:

```
link_to(event.name, event_path(event), :rel => 'shadowbox;width=500;height=300;')
```

Note that you might need to change some of the code above, depending on where you extracted the Shadowbox source files. Hope that helps.

Answer (score 2):

Opening new window isn't actually rails responsibility. You should do it by using javascript snippet. Consider this:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    window.open('desired/URL', 'windowName', 'height=200,width=200');
</script>
```

you should suit the third argument to your needs. Look at: http://www.javascript-coder.com/window-popup/javascript-window-open.phtml

Notice, that there is no problem with using rails snippets in js (<%= %>), so you can make link flexible by using some helper method.