# How come jquery doesn't show my div in a dialog?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I'm trying to follow [this basic jquery dialog article](http://blog.nemikor.com/2009/04/08/basic-usage-of-the-jquery-ui-dialog/) on how to open a modal dialog. The code goes like so.

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>Basic usage of the jQuery UI dialog</title>

    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.7.1/themes/base/jquery-ui.css">

    <script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.3.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.7.1/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function() {
        var $dialog = $('<div></div>')
            .html('This dialog will show every time!')
            .dialog({
                autoOpen: false,
                title: 'Basic Dialog'
            });

        $('#opener').click(function() {
            $dialog.dialog('open');
            // prevent the default action, e.g., following a link
            return false;
        });
    });
    </script>
</head>
<body>

<p>This is an example from the Nemikor Blog article <a href="http://blog.nemikor.com/2009/04/08/basic-usage-of-the-jquery-ui-dialog/">Basic usage of the jQuery UI dialog</a>.</p>

<button id="opener">Open the dialog</button>

</body>
</html>
```

(where I've skipped a page counter in the sake of brevity). The original example works fine; a modal dialog is displayed.

Now I'd like to combine this awesomeness with my rails app, creating a modal dialog as indicated in [chourobin's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7268666/182048). I've added a

```
<div class="modal" style="display:none;">
  <h1>Test</h1>
</div>
```

part to the body, and changed my `$('#opener')` to

```
$('#opener').click(function() {
  $(".modal").dialog('open');
  //$('.modal').css( "border", "3px solid red" );
  return false;
});
```

Unfortunately, no dialog is opened. Yet, when I set the `modal` div to be displayed by default, and comment out the `dialog` call and uncomment the `css` call in the above code, jquery successfully identifies the `modal` class and paints a 3 pixel, red, solid border around my div.

My question is: why aren't jquery displaying the (clearly identifiable) `div` in a dialog as in my initial attempt?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$(".modal").dialog();
```

Is what you're looking for

Comment: you're absolutely right. I've seen that around, I just didn't have the fantasy to try it out. Thanks! :)

Answer (score 0):

Since the `<div class="modal">` is not visible when the page is loaded you need to use the .on() method and bind the event to the parent to the `<div>`.

Try something like

```
$('body').on('click','.modal',function(){
//your code here
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You have two different calls for the dialog. On the first call you have set some parameters. On the second call you have not.

I would suggest to remove the inline style attribute (since this is keeping it hidden) and add a param for the dialog. like your working example did.

```
<!-- Removed the inline style -->
<div class="modal" title="Testing the Modal Code">
  <h1>Test</h1>
</div>

//-- Adding this
$('.modal').dialog({
    autoOpen: false
});

//-- Using the same call
$('#opener').click(function() {
    $(".modal").dialog('open');
    //$('.modal').css( "border", "3px solid red" );
});
```

This should provide the result you want.

Answer (score 0):

The dialog will open with:

`$(".modal").dialog();`

Here is an example: http://jsfiddle.net/nH339/